# Why is WPF Aplication Not Launching both .exe Applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I have made a very simple WPF application that is intended to have a couple of options:
Option 1 is to launch a PDF file
Option 2 is to launch a couple of exe files needed to run my software.

The problem is that on the machine I have developed this on it does open both .exe files just fine, but the strange thig is that when I try this on my HP Laptop it only wants to open the unity3d exe file and not the Voice Server exe file.

Does anybody have any idea why this is the case, it's driving me nuts trying to figure it out. here is how I have by button call coded in C#

```
public static void LaunchKOS()
{
    var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    var desktopPathkos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    // Launch Voice Server
    var combinedPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Knight O S Beta01_Data/voice-recognition-server-pc/VoiceServer/bin/Release/KittVoiceServer");
    Process.Start(combinedPath);
    // Launch Knight O.S. Unity Settings Window
    var combinedPathkos = Path.Combine(desktopPathkos, "Knight O S Beta01");
    Process.Start(combinedPathkos);


    // Close This Window
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

**EDIT:**

On the outside chance that for some reason it did not like doing both .exe files from one button I have even tried just launching the Voiceserver.exe from the one button call and I still get the same result where it will launch it on the machine I have developed the app on but not on any other machine despite the fact that the file folders are exactly the same??

There has to be some logical reason for why this is not working??

Anyone?!?

**EDIT: More than one way to skin a cat**

Well, it may not be the most elegant way to have solved the problem but I've managed to come up with a work-around.
What I did was create a shortcut of the VoiceServer.exe and then in my button code execute the shortcut and now it will open both .exe files.

It's beyond stupid that I should even have to do that, but that's what I ended up doing. :/

Comment: are you starting the same executable twice? perhaps the executable itself has a mechanism to terminate if an instance is already running.

Comment: permission issue?

Comment: Quick note: I would get in a habit of adding file extensions to your filenames. There will be times where a file or open due to the lack of the file extension. But for your question, have you tried launching the application from the command line manually? Have you tried debugging `combinedPath` and copy and pasting that value into the console to see if it actually launches the application?

Comment: @dlatikay No I'm trying to start two separate .exe apps

Steve I get no permissions issues, I have launched these files on these machines before.

Chris On my one PC which is an Alienware the two apps launch just fine but when I copy the same files over to a different PC only the one .exe file will launch from the launcher.

Comment: Michael - I would definitely add the .exe extension for each exe you are running.  Just to play it safe.  You could be one update differ that can screw you up.

Comment: Thanks @SASS_Shooter I have tried that too even and I still get the same results, my launcher just refuses to launch the voiceserver.exe on any other computer I copy the files over too.

Answer (score 0):

The folder separator for local files paths is "\" rather than "/".

Path.Combine() is defined with a params parameter, so to avoid issues with \ being treated as an escape character, it's cleaner to just pass each folder name as a separate string.

```
var combinedPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Knight O S Beta01_Data", "voice-recognition-server-pc", "VoiceServer", "bin", "Release", "KittVoiceServer");
```

Comment: Thanks @Peregrine I tried this method and I'm still getting the same issues with it only wanting to launch the one exe file on other machines. :(